# Laravel using loadViewComponentsAs method from SurviceProvider without creating the package

Tags: laravel, package

When installing jetstream with it's authentication/authorization system laravel developer receive scaffolding with lots of views and view-components.

Firstly those views are in vendor\laravel\jetstream\resources\views\components\ folder.

Then when developer publishes views according to jeststream installation: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html#livewire-components

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

Those views/components appears at resources\views\vendor\jetstream\components.

The links to those views on the blade templates are:

```
<x-jet-welcome />
```

or to unify

```
<x-jet-someJetElement />
```

This corresponds with laravel blade documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#view-components

We need to register those aliases in SurviceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewComponentsAs('courier', [
        Alert::class,
        Button::class,
    ]);
}
```

And then use them like this:

```
<x-courier-alert />

<x-courier-button />
```

My question is if we can register those aliases without creating a package?
So what I did:

1. Added aliases in AppServiceProvider - default service provider for users.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\View\Components\Alert;
use App\View\Components\Button;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewComponentsAs('nopackage', [
            Alert::class,
            Button::class,
            ]);
    }
}
```

2. Created two components app\View\Components:

Alert.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Alert extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.alert');
    }
}
```

Button.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Button extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.button');
    }
}
```

3. Created two view components resources\views\components:

alert.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello from Alert!</h2>
</div>
```

button.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello from button!</h2>
</div>
```

4. Created view resources\views\bladetest.blade.php:

```
<h1>
    Hello from blade test!
</h1>
<x-nopackage-Alert/>
```

5. Created route:

```
Route::view('/bladetest', 'bladetest');
```

And it does not work: "Unable to locate a class or view for component [nopackage-Alert]."

What I am doing wrong?